# can I be SP developer without be a good SP admin?

Tags: 2013

I'm an ASP.net developer and I want to learn sharepoint developer.

can I be a SP developer without be a good SP admin?

I feed I should learn a lot of administration topics before going to development. is it right?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extremely Short Version: **No** -- you'll need to be at least proficient at administration

---

It really is a requirement that you be at least proficient at being an administrator in order to effectively develop solutions for SharePoint. You have to understand how all of the parts interact and are administered, in order to leverage them effectively when you build solutions.

If you need to know 'a lot' is debatable, but you definitely need the basics.